# Changing Size of PictureBox in Stretch Size Mode to achieve closest Aspect Ratio Match

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, picturebox, system.drawing

I have picturebox  whose sizemode is set to stretch.I cannot change it to zoom or normal due to some programming requirements.

I want to adjust the size of the picturebox by the smallest factor,so as to achieve the closest aspect ratio match.

I don't want to alter the picturebox sizemode by a large amount.Just want to prevent the image from being appearing  stretched or shrunken.

Comment: you do have the maximum width/height, right?

Comment: @TaW Yeah......

Comment: so you get wo ratios: pbMaxW/pbMaxH and imgW / imgH. the larger determines if you keep the width or height of the pbox. the other side then can be calculated.. - See fubo's short version!